# Loading multiple json files and add path name as column

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I am currently loading into a spark DataFrame all the json files present in my_folder using the following code:

```
data = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("/path/my_folder")
```

Example with two json files:

- filename1: aaa.json
- filename2: bbb.json

I get the following DataFrame:

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | Paris |
| John | Prior |
| Nick | Pair |
| Louis | Pit |
| Georges | Pais |

I now want to save the name of each file into an additional column:

- filename1: aaa.json
- filename2: bbb.json

To get the following DataFrame:

| first_name | last_name | filename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | Paris | aaa.json |
| John | Prior | aaa.json |
| Nick | Pair | aaa.json |
| Louis | Pit | bbb.json |
| Georges | Pais | bbb.json |

I have too many files to loop over all of it one after the other. Is there another way?

Comment: Create the `filename` column using `input_file_name()`. See this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name.html#pyspark-sql-functions-input-file-name) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of input_file_name() pyspark function like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

json_file = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("/FileStore/tables/dummy_file-4.json")

new_df = json_file.withColumn('filename', f.input_file_name())

new_df.show(5, False)

+----------+---------+----------------------------------------+
|first_name|last_name|filename                                |
+----------+---------+----------------------------------------+
|Jack      |Paris    |dbfs:/FileStore/tables/dummy_file-4.json|
+----------+---------+----------------------------------------+
```